# Python recursive function not returning

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function that returns the position of a word in a sorted word list, or return `None` when the word is not found. The following is the code:

```
def partition(t,kw,upper,lower):
    if ((upper-lower) > 1):
        pivot = lower + (upper-lower)//2
        print("pivot is now {}".format(pivot))
        if (kw >= t[pivot]):
            lower = pivot
            print("searching on the right",upper,lower)
            return(partition(t,kw,upper,lower))
        
        elif (kw <= t[pivot-1]):
            upper = pivot-1
            print("searching on the left",upper,lower)
            return(partition(t,kw,upper,lower))

        else:
            return None 
            #that means the keyword is between t[pivot-1] and t[pivot]
            #which means it doesnt exist in the list
    if (upper - lower) <= 1:
        if (kw == t[upper]):
            print("found element {} at upper bound {}".format(kw,upper))
            return(upper)
        elif (kw == t[lower]):
            print("found element {} at lower bound {}".format(kw,lower))
            return(lower)
        else:
            return None

def search(t, kw):
    u = len(t)
    partition(t,kw,u,0)
```

As you can see I returned the function whenever I called it(not returning is a common mistake in using recursive calls). At the same time, here's the sample array I was using:

```
['', '', '150', '150', '1997,with', '36', '49', 'An', 'Annotated', 'Annotation', 'Bibliography', 'China', 'Chinese', 'Chinese', 'Classical', 'During', 'Dynasty', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'In', 'It', 'Kong', 'Kong', 'Kong', 'Kong,', 'Kong.', 'Mainland', 'Poets', 'Qing', 'They', 'Together,', 'Writings', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'active', 'activity,', 'addition', 'almost', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'annotations', 'anthologies', 'basic', 'been', 'before.', 'bibliographic', 'bibliographies,', 'by', 'carry', 'ci-poetry', 'ci-poetry', 'classical', 'collected', 'commentaries', 'compilation,', 'compilations', 'compiled', 'covered,', 'development', 'events', 'focused', 'form', 'form', 'formation,', 'from', 'from', 'has', 'help', 'hidden', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'includes', 'individual', 'information', 'information', 'introduces', 'invaluable', 'is', 'late', 'literary', 'literati', 'literature', 'literature.', 'membership,', 'most', 'never', 'not', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'offer', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'order', 'over', 'past', 'periods', 'pioneer', 'pity', 'poetic', 'poetry', 'poetry', 'poetry', 'poet’s', 'political', 'previous', 'previously', 'published', 'refuge', 'research', 'sequel', 'shi-', 'shi-', 'societies', 'societies', 'societies', 'societies.', 'societies.', 'splendor,', 'that', 'that', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'these', 'these', 'these', 'this', 'times', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'took', 'tools', 'topic', 'tradition.', 'turmoil', 'two', 'uncover', 'understand', 'understanding', 'unique', 'up', 'various', 'very', 'volume,', 'which', 'works,', 'worthwhile', 'would', 'years,']
```

I was searching for the word `"Qing"`, it should end up in the 31st position.
Right now it seems like the function could find the word I need, but couldn't return:

```
the result is
pivot is now 92
searching on the left 91 0
pivot is now 45
searching on the left 44 0
pivot is now 22
searching on the right 44 22
pivot is now 33
searching on the left 32 22
pivot is now 27
searching on the right 32 27
pivot is now 29
searching on the right 32 29
pivot is now 30
searching on the right 32 30
pivot is now 31
searching on the right 32 31
found element Qing at lower bound 31
None
```

I tried searching for issues relating to recursive functions but didn't seem much related content. Most posts on SO are caused by not returning the recursive function, and I am really not sure what's wrong in here.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* [mcve] – that includes how the code is actually called.

Comment: Are you simply wanting to return `31` from  `def search`? If so, you need to add a `return` statement!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function seems to be working. I think you just forgot to return from search, i.e.

```
def search(t, kw):
    u = len(t)
    lower = partition(t,kw,u,0)
    return lower
```

Outputs

```
...
searching on the right 32 30
pivot is now 31
searching on the right 32 31
found element Qing at lower bound 31
31
```

Answer (score 2):

**single purpose, simplified**

As it's written `partition` is a big function with many parameters trying to do many things. Is it possible to separate some of its concerns and make it more usable? Can we abstract away some of the complexity to make the function easier to write and less prone to error?

To look at ways to improve `partition`, we will first look at Python's `range` data structure. In your implementation, you have used the following arithmetic to arrive at a solution -

- `upper - lower > 1`
- `lower + (upper - lower) // 2`
- `kw <= t[pivot - 1]`
- `upper = pivot - 1`
- `upper - lower <= 1`

The cognitive overhead above is tremendous and the potential for [Off-By-One Errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) is high. Using a range, `r`, we can find the pivot `p` and efficiently slice using `[]`, and simultaneously side-step all of our headaches -

```py
r = range(1,100)
p = len(r) // 2
print("input", r)        # input range(1, 100)
print("pivot", p)        # pivot 49
print("guess", r[p])     # guess 50
print("left ", r[0:p])   # left  range(0, 50)
print("right", r[p+1:])  # right range(51, 100)
```

Here is the same arithmetic applied to a different range -

```py
r = range(44,66)
p = len(r) // 2
print("input", r)        # input range(44, 66)
print("pivot", p)        # pivot 11
print("guess", r[p])     # guess 55
print("left ", r[0:p])   # left  range(44, 55)
print("right", r[p+1:])  # right range(56, 66)
```

**partition**

Using these properties, we can write a generic `partition` that *only* concerns itself with a single range -

```py
def partition(r):
  if len(r) == 0: return (yield None)             # base case
  pivot = len(r) // 2                             # pivot
  (a, b) = yield r[pivot]                         # guess
  if a < b: yield from partition(r[0:pivot])      # recur on left
  elif a > b: yield from partition(r[pivot + 1:]) # recur on right
  else: return None                               # equal
```

Above, our function has no concerns for a list of words, `t`, a keyword to search for, `kw`, nor individual `lower` and `upper` bounds. Most importantly arithmetic is minimized, using only `// 2` to find a `pivot` and `+1` to calculate the right-side range. The potential for range errors has been significantly reduced.

**search**

Now we can write `search` as a specialization of `partition` which takes a list of words, `t`, and a keyword to search for, `kw` -

```py
def search(t, kw):
  def loop(p, v):                     # loop
    i = p.send(v)                     # get guess
    if i is None: return None         # base case
    elif kw == t[i]: return i         # found it! return i
    else: return loop(p, (kw, t[i]))  # recur with comparables
  r = range(0, len(t))                # init range
  return loop(partition(r), None)     # loop over partition of r
```

This is a simple `loop` over `partition`. On each iteration, we get an index, `i`, from our partition generator, `p`. If there is no index, we have reached the end of the search. Otherwise if `kw` is equal to `t[i]` we found the answer and can return it. Otherwise `kw` is *not* equal to `t[i]` and so we recur on `p` sending `(kw, t[i])` as the next comparison.

Using our `search` function is straightforward -

```py
r = search(words, "Qing")
if r is None:
  print("no result")
else:
  print(f"found at index: {r}")
```

```
found at index: 31
```

If we search for a word that does not exist -

```py
r = search(words, "Wxyz")
if r is None:
  print("no result")
else:
  print(f"found at index: {r}")
```

```
no result
```

**handle with care**

Python generators have a unique interface and they're one of the rare exceptions where using `try..except` for program control flow is acceptable. Above I explicitly `yield None` in `partition` and check for `None` in `loop` but Python offers a `StopIteration` exception that allows us remove some of this clutter -

```py
def partition(r):
  if len(r) == 0: return                    # stop
  p = len(r) // 2                           # pivot
  (a, b) = yield r[p]                       # guess
  if a < b: yield from partition(r[0:p])    # recur left
  if a > b: yield from partition(r[p+1:])   # recur right
                                            # (implict) return None
```

Now when we write `search`, we can skip null-checks for `None` and proceed with the assumption that we have a valid guess. Otherwise if the generator is exhausted, we catch the stop exception and return `None` -

```py
def search(t, kw):
  def loop(p, v):                           # loop
    i = p.send(v)                           # get guess 
    if kw == t[i]: return i                 # match?
    return loop(p, (kw, t[i]))              # recur
  try:
    r = range(0, len(t))
    return loop(partition(r), None)
  except StopIteration:                     # base case
    return None
```

Over time I have come to prefer this interface as it reduces explicit nulls and the need to check for them. These new implementations of `partition` and `search` behave the same and produce the same output.

**decoupling side effects**

Another important thing to note here is that side effects like `print` are not present in the `partition` function. This makes it usable in other parts of your program that might compare other data structures or wishes to format output in a different way -

Below we can write a simple modification to `search` which gives you debug output -

```py
def search(t, kw):
  def loop(p, v):
    i = p.send(v)
    print(f"searching index {i}: {kw} == {t[i]}?") # one change
    if kw == t[i]: return i
    return loop(p, (kw, t[i]))
  try:
    r = range(0, len(t))
    return loop(partition(r), None)
  except StopIteration:
    return None
```

Let's see the output of our examples with the debug in place -

```py
r = search(words, "Qing")
if r is None:
  print("no result")
else:
  print(f"found at index: {r}")
```

```
searching index 92: Qing == literati?
searching index 46: Qing == and?
searching index 23: Qing == It?
searching index 35: Qing == a?
searching index 29: Qing == Mainland?
searching index 32: Qing == They?
searching index 31: Qing == Qing?
found at index: 31
```

And our second example -

```py
r = search(words, "Wxyz")
if r is None:
  print("no result")
else:
  print(f"found at index: {r}")
```

```
searching index 92: Wxyz == literati?
searching index 46: Wxyz == and?
searching index 23: Wxyz == It?
searching index 35: Wxyz == a?
searching index 29: Wxyz == Mainland?
searching index 32: Wxyz == They?
searching index 34: Wxyz == Writings?
no result
```

**without recursion**

You'll often hear people talking-down about recursion in Python. Because binary search is very efficient, it would take a monstrous input for the recursive solution above to overflow the stack. That said, there's nothing stopping us from writing `partition` and `search` using iteration in place of recursion, if we wish -

```py
def partition(r):
  while len(r):
    p = len(r) // 2
    (a, b) = yield r[p]
    if a < b: r = r[0:p]
    if a > b: r = r[p+1:]
    if a == b: break
```

```py
def search(t, kw):
  try:
    r = range(0, len(t))
    p = partition(r)
    v = None
    while True:
      i = p.send(v)
      if kw == t[i]: return i
      v = (kw, t[i])
  except StopIteration:
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66458113/13552470) great answer, you neglected to add a `return` statement to your `search` function. There are, however, things that can be improved in your code:

```
def partition(t, kw, upper, lower):
    if upper - lower > 1:
        pivot = lower + (upper - lower) // 2
        print("pivot is now {}".format(pivot))
        if kw >= t[pivot]:
            lower = pivot
            print("searching on the right", upper, lower)
            return partition(t, kw, upper, lower) 
        if kw <= t[pivot - 1]:
            upper = pivot - 1
            print("searching on the left", upper, lower)
            return partition(t, kw, upper, lower)
    if upper - lower <= 1:
        if kw == t[upper]:
            print("found element {} at upper bound {}".format(kw, upper))
            return upper 
        if kw == t[lower]:
            print("found element {} at lower bound {}".format(kw, lower))
            return lower

def search(t, kw):
    u = len(t)
    return partition(t, kw, u, 0)

lst = ['', '', '150', '150', '1997,with', '36', '49', 'An', 'Annotated', 'Annotation', 'Bibliography', 'China', 'Chinese', 'Chinese', 'Classical', 'During', 'Dynasty', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'Hong', 'In', 'It', 'Kong', 'Kong', 'Kong', 'Kong,', 'Kong.', 'Mainland', 'Poets', 'Qing', 'They', 'Together,', 'Writings', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'active', 'activity,', 'addition', 'almost', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'annotations', 'anthologies', 'basic', 'been', 'before.', 'bibliographic', 'bibliographies,', 'by', 'carry', 'ci-poetry', 'ci-poetry', 'classical', 'collected', 'commentaries', 'compilation,', 'compilations', 'compiled', 'covered,', 'development', 'events', 'focused', 'form', 'form', 'formation,', 'from', 'from', 'has', 'help', 'hidden', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'includes', 'individual', 'information', 'information', 'introduces', 'invaluable', 'is', 'late', 'literary', 'literati', 'literature', 'literature.', 'membership,', 'most', 'never', 'not', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'of', 'offer', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'order', 'over', 'past', 'periods', 'pioneer', 'pity', 'poetic', 'poetry', 'poetry', 'poetry', 'poet’s', 'political', 'previous', 'previously', 'published', 'refuge', 'research', 'sequel', 'shi-', 'shi-', 'societies', 'societies', 'societies', 'societies.', 'societies.', 'splendor,', 'that', 'that', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'these', 'these', 'these', 'this', 'times', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'took', 'tools', 'topic', 'tradition.', 'turmoil', 'two', 'uncover', 'understand', 'understanding', 'unique', 'up', 'various', 'very', 'volume,', 'which', 'works,', 'worthwhile', 'would', 'years,']
print(search(lst, "Qing"))
```

Output:

```
pivot is now 92
searching on the left 91 0
pivot is now 45
searching on the left 44 0
pivot is now 22
searching on the right 44 22
pivot is now 33
searching on the left 32 22
pivot is now 27
searching on the right 32 27
pivot is now 29
searching on the right 32 29
pivot is now 30
searching on the right 32 30
pivot is now 31
searching on the right 32 31
found element Qing at lower bound 31
31
```

Actually, every second `if` statement can be eliminated as well *(as in, remove the `if` line and unindent its contents)*, but for the sake of readability, leaving them is fine.

Also, if you're using python 3, the `"Example number {}".format(5)` elements can be replaced with `f"Example number {5}"`.