# Returning "None" instead of the value of the variable

Tags: python-3.x, oop

When this function is called in my program, it runs correctly for the array inputted and the value is stored in tempArray when I debug and step through it. However when returning tempArray when the count variable is equal to the length of numArray (line 5), it seems to call the function again on line 12 when stepping on debug, and then returns "None" instead of tempArray.

Just thought I'd mention for A.binary_gap_search, I do call at the bottom of the whole program A =  so this shouldn't be the issue I'm assuming.

Any help massively appreciated, thanks.

Also another side note in case people are wondering, the binary gap calculation might be different to what you would assume, but my practical question defines the binary gap a different way to what it says online.

'''

```
def binary_gap_search(self, numArray, tempArray, i):
    count = i
    if numArray[count] == "1":
        count += 1
        if count == len(numArray):
            return tempArray
        else:
            while numArray[count] == "0":
                count += 1
            tempArray.append(count)
            if count < len(numArray):
                A.binary_gap_search(numArray, tempArray, count)
            else:
                return tempArray
    elif numArray[count] == "0":
        return count
```

'''

Comment: the numArray is a string that is turned into an array. So it should be "1".

Comment: you're not returning it `return A.binary_gap_search(numArray, tempArray, count)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python recursive function not returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66457965/python-recursive-function-not-returning)